# Oracle SQL query question

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to complete this Oracle SQL query with no luck.

"List the department that has the least average cost. (Hint: `SELECT  MIN(AVG(cost)`) is valid as long as no other column is combined in the SELECT statement. You can combine the above as a subquery with another query)"

I'm able to get it to display the Depts with their average cost, but when I try to work in `MIN` it breaks. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT DeptNo, AVG(projcost) FROM projects, clinicians WHERE clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno GROUP BY DeptNo;
```

That will give me the depts and their AVG, but when I change `AVG(projcost)` to be `MIN(AVG(projcost)` it breaks. The hint is to make it a subquery but I can't figure out how to do that yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A subquery is a query within a query. I won't give you the answer but here is a link that describe subqueries: [Oracle Subquery on Tech on the net][1]. I think you will get more out of the assignment learning how to do it on your own rather than fishing for what someone else's answers.


  [1]: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php

Comment: @Bernard ERROR: group function is not allowed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  MIN(q1.AvgProjCost)
FROM (SELECT 
        DeptNo, 
        AVG(projcost) as AvgProjCost 
      FROM projects, clinicians 
      WHERE clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno 
      GROUP BY DeptNo) q1
```

**EDITED**
Suppose I Have the following department project costs

```
Department ProjectCost
1          15
1          15
1          15
2          16
2          16
3          17
3          17
4          18
```

These project Costs would render the following averages

```
Department Average
1          15
2          16
3          17
4          18
```

The minimum average for each department is still the same result set.

**EDITED AGAIN**

If you really must have Minimum Average for each department then this will work

```
SELECT 
  q1.Dept,
  MIN(q1.AvgProjCost)
FROM (SELECT 
        DeptNo, 
        AVG(projcost) as AvgProjCost 
      FROM projects, clinicians 
      WHERE clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno 
      GROUP BY DeptNo) q1
GROUP BY q1.Dept
```

However you will soon realize that this result set is and will always be the same as

```
      SELECT 
        DeptNo, 
        AVG(projcost) as AvgProjCost 
      FROM projects, clinicians 
      WHERE clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno 
      GROUP BY DeptNo
```

**EDITED Once More**

To obtain the department with the smallest average project cost

```
SELECT 
  q1.Dept,
  q1.AvgProjCost
FROM (SELECT 
        DeptNo, 
        AVG(projcost) as AvgProjCost 
      FROM projects, clinicians 
      WHERE clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno 
      GROUP BY DeptNo) q1
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY AvgProjCost DESC
```

Comment: That one is the closest so far, except the output only shows the lowest MIN(AVG()) and doesn't show DeptNo.

Comment: @LunarZer0 OK so if you take the Avg(of project cost) grouping by DeptNo then you will get 1 row for each department.  If you get the min of the Averages just queried, grouping by department you will get the same result.  look at my edit in my answer

Comment: Your solution does work in giving me the lowest average by dept, however the problem is simple that they are wanting the output to say "DeptNo, Min(AVG(projcost))" and it is only giving me "MIN(AVG(projcost))" I'm trying to work in the DeptNo output.

Comment: @LunarZer0 Your last comment is seems incomplete

Comment: @John Yea I accidentally hit the enter button while typing. I did edit it to finish the sentence. Let me know if you cannot see the edit.

Comment: @LunarZer0 If what you say is correct I believe you just want to take the average for each department. Handling minimum of each average for each department would be redundant. Read my edited answer

Comment: @John: This is the exact question I have "List the department that has the least average cost. (Hint: SELECT MIN(AVG(cost)) is valid as long as no other column is combined in the SELECT statement. You can combine the above as a subquery with another query)" To me it says it is asking for the dept to be outputted more than the value. I hope that clears up what is being asked.

Comment: @LunarZer0.. I updated my answer one more time for you. have a look.  By the way is this homework?

Comment: @John it is a practice problem for a class to study for an exam. I do appreciate all your help. Your code works in displaying 1 line that is the Min(AVG(projcost)) but it is supposed to display which DeptNo has the MIN(AVG(projcost)) instead.

Comment: @LunarZer0... I posted a query that will return the Department with the smallest Average Project Cost

Comment: If two depts have the same average cost this query will show you only one dept. Is that ok? If not, look at Cybernate's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH avgData AS
SELECT a.*,
             RANK() OVER(ORDER BY avg_cost) RN
  FROM 
    (
        SELECT  DeptNo, 
                    AVG(projcost) avg_cost,
                    projects.ROWNUM rn
        FROM    projects, 
                    clinicians 
        WHERE   clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno 
        GROUP BY DeptNo
    ) a
SELECT *
  FROM avgData
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT TOP 1
        DeptNo
       ,AVG(projcost)
    FROM
        projects
       ,clinicians
    WHERE
        clinicians.Clinicianno = projects.Clinicianno
    GROUP BY
        DeptNo
    ORDER BY
        AVG(projcost) ;

Answer (score -1):

Try this....

Sample Data

`DEPTNO| AVG_COST
100    |8601.333333
30     |4150
90     |19333.33333
20     |9500
70     |10000
110    |10154
50     |3475.555556
80     |8955.882353
40     |6500
60     |5760
10     |4400`

`SELECT DEPTNO,AVG_COST
FROM
  (SELECT P.DEPTNO,
    (AVG(C.COST)) AVG_COST
  FROM PROJECTS P,
    CLINICIANS  C
  WHERE P.DEPTNO=C.DEPTNO
  GROUP BY P.DEPTNO
  )
WHERE AVG_COST=
  (SELECT MIN(AVG_COST)
  FROM
    (SELECT P.DEPTNO,
    (AVG(C.COST)) AVG_COST
  FROM PROJECTS P,
    CLINICIANS  C
  WHERE P.DEPTNO=C.DEPTNO
  GROUP BY P.DEPTNO
    )
  );`

Above query will give you below result

`DEPTNO| AVG_COST
50     |3475.555556`